# Modal Form Data Not Submitting

Tags: php, html

For my school project, I have the following code to upload a file to a server. When the upload is complete and the file is process, the page reloads and a modal window appears for the user to verify some of the data. The problem is that when the user clicks the submit button, the PHP code to handle to handle to form submission doesn't get executed. The echo statement to print the "no" alert works, but nothing inside the if statement executes.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <form class="form-signin text-center" action="#">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading"><a href="."><img src="img/logo.png" style="width:300px; height:100px;"></a></h2>
        <h4>Resume Upload</h4>
        <br>
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION["upload-success"]) && !isset($_POST["update"])){
                if ($_SESSION["upload-success"] = true){
                    echo "
                        <div class='alert alert-info' role='alert' id='verify-banner'><strong>Success!</strong> Resume uploaded successfully.</a></div>
                        <script type='text/javascript'>
                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                $('#edit').modal('show'); 
                            });
                        </script>
                    ";
                }else{
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'><strong>Error!</strong> An error occurred while uploading the resume.</div>";
                }
                unset($_SESSION["upload-success"]);
            }
        ?>
        <div class="form-group align-items-center">
            <div class="input-group input-file" name="image">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-choose" type="button">Choose</button>
                </span>
                <input type="text" placeholder='Choose a file...' style="padding-right: 105px;"/>
            </div>
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary upload" type="submit">Upload</button>
        </div>
        <div id="progressbar" class="progress progress-striped active" style="display:none;">
            <div class="progress-bar" style="width:0%"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="modal fade" id="edit">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Verify Resume Data</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form name="update" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">First Name</label>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['fname']?>" name="fname" id="fname">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Last Name</label>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['lname']?>" name="lname" id="lname">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Email Address</label>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <input class="form-control" type="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']?>" name="email" id="email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Phone Number</label>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" step="1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['phone']?>" name="phone" id="phone">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Notes</label>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <textarea class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="notes" id="notes"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update" id="update"  formmethod="post">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
        if (isset($_POST["update"])){
            require_once("db".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."db.php");
            $userid = $_SESSION["new-user-id"];
            $note = $_POST["notes"];
            $mydb->query("UPDATE account SET `FirstName`='".$_POST["fname"]."', `LastName`='".$_POST["lname"]."', `EmailAddress`='".$_POST["email"]."', `PhoneNumber`='".$_POST["phone"]."'' WHERE `UserID`='$userid';");
            $mydb->query("INSERT INTO resume_notes(`UserID`, `Note`) VALUES('$userid', '$note') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Note`='$note';");
            //echo "<script>alert('yes');</script>";
            unset($_SESSION["fname"]);
            unset($_SESSION["lname"]);
            unset($_SESSION["email"]);
            unset($_SESSION["phone"]);
            unset($_SESSION["new-user-id"]);
            unset($_POST["update"]);
        }else{
            //echo "<script>alert('no');</script>";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: @bob Not sure if that's the case. I've done something similar before and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: in your first version of the posted code the modal was outside the <form> + the question was slightly different, hinting that you try to get form values from that modal, which couldnt work since the modal was not inside the form